# Pulling both values from 2d array but only showing one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

Hi I'm attempting to pull only the first word in the array I've built — and then on click of "flip" — show the antonym it's paired with. i.e. pull 0 and 1 *but only show 0* until a button is clicked (then have 0 switch out for 1). The code below works fine, but as of right now, it's pulling and appending both words to #input.

Here's my JS:

```
var words = [];
words[0] = ['Budding','Accomplished']; 
words[1] = ['Curious','Certain']; 
words[2] = ['Realistic','Idealistic']; 
words[3] = ['Practicle','Imaginative']; 

function random_sort () {
      return (0.5 - Math.random() );
}

words.sort(random_sort);

var i = 0,
    n = words.length;

$("#forward").data('dir', 1);
$("#back").data('dir', -1);

$("#forward, #back").on('click', function() {
    i = (i + $(this).data('dir') + n) % n;
    $("#input").hide().html(words[i]).fadeIn(100);
    $(words[i][1]).hide();
});

$("#back").trigger('click');
```

and my html:

```
<object id="back" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/arrow.svg"></object>
<p id="input"></p>
<object id="forward" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/arrow.svg"></object>

<img id="flip" src="images/fliptext.svg">
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where is your html?

Comment: I've added the html.

Comment: since you are using svg you should provide them too. it's better to see a working version (snippet here on so or a jsfiddle)

Comment: @Dekel this has nothing to do with SVG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is `$("#input2").hide().html(words[i]).fadeIn(100);` specifically `html(words[i])` which is equal to `html(['Budding','Accomplished'])` and will concatenate the array before adding it to the html.

Change that to `$("#input2").hide().html(words[i][0]).fadeIn(100);`  where `words[i][0]` is specifically selecting the word at the first index in the array.

```js
var words = [];
words[0] = ['Budding','Accomplished']; 
words[1] = ['Curious','Certain']; 
words[2] = ['Realistic','Idealistic']; 
words[3] = ['Practicle','Imaginative']; 
 
var i=0;
$("#input").hide().html(words[i]).fadeIn(100);
$("#input2").hide().html(words[i][0]).fadeIn(100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Wrong</strong><div id="input"> </div><br>
<strong>Right</strong><div id="input2"> </div>
```

Comment: Aha! This makes perfect sense. Appreciate the comment,